# OSX Java Remote Debug for packaged app

Tags: java, macos, debugging

Do you know how to debug a packaged (inside app directory) java app on OSX? I tried to add this:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=6000,suspend=y
```

in the java control panel without success. When I run

```
ps aux | grep java
```

I don't see any java instance running, the app shows as a process named as the application's name.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You should add and accept a self-answer, so the question shows up as answered in the main list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the parameters to the file info.plist inside the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that option is specific to IBM Websphere JVM (might be wrong here). Check what JVM you're using, normally OSX ships with standard Oracle Hotspot VM

Also try debugging your app via eclipse, it should be easier to setup

Comment: It's not specific IBM JVM, I'm using the same for debugging on Linux and Windows, the problem is on Mac because is packaged. I'm trying to debug a open with double click behavior.

Comment: On OSX you can right click the *.app file and 'Show Package Contents', try fiddling around with config file inside it maybe you can insert the extra parameters somehow

Comment: Thanks, I added the parameters to the info.plist file.